# Gridview_RowCommand getting executed after loading of pop up window

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a search screen where I am using a GridView, in GridView I have `<asp:LinkButton>` and in its command argument I am using value for that column and `(Container.DataItemIndex+1)` to find the row number of item on which I have clicked. In `Gridview_RowCommand` I am assigning these values in session variable so that they could be passed to pop up window.

Let's say my search screen has populated two rows, on click of first row it works fine and I can access session variables in pop up window; however when I click on 2nd row's linkbutton pop up window gets refreshed first and then `Gridview_RowCommand` gets executed later because of which I am not getting updated values in my session variables.

Below is my linkbutton in aspx page: Popup window which gets invoked on click of link button is an HTML page having two frames each containing on aspx page.

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File Name" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btn"  runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Empid")%>'
CommandName="Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Empid") + "," 
+ (Container.DataItemIndex+1)%>' OnClientClick='<%# Eval("Empid",
"window.open(\"abc.html\",null,\"location=0,status=0,toolbar=0
,menubar=0,resizable=1\",\"true\");")%>'/>
        </ItemTemplate>  
</Columns>
```

Below code is aspx.cs code where I am storing values of empid and Container.DataItemIndex+1 in session variables.

```
protected void grdDisplayResult_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "Click":
        {
            string[] arg = new string[1];
            arg = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(',');
            Session["Empid"] = arg[0];
            Session["RowNum"] = arg[1];
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I also have a pop up window which gets popped up when user clicks on link button.

Comment: Can _you_ please share some code if possible?

Comment: I would think onClientClick will always happen before the row command handler, as the latter will happen on the server during postback. Why not pass the values to the HTML page via query string?

Comment: Thanks Tim i am now using querystring and it solved my problem